# I've got a problem where I want to create a voice channel every time 2 people use the same dedicated command, which I managed to do but

Tags: discord.py

the problem is I can't connect the 2 users to it because I don't have the ID of the channel that has been created
Look at this code

```
async def join(ctx,i=[0],c=[0]):
    author = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    if i[0] == 0:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"""Voice chat #  {c[0]}""")
        i[0] = 0
        c[0]+=1
    i[0] += 1
    if i[0] == 2:
        i[0] = 0
    print(i[0])
    return i[0]
```

Could anyone potentially help me with this?
For some elaboration - What happens here is, if the user types !join It will create a voice channel, in which i want the user to be sent into immediately, then a different user also uses !join and gets sent into the same channel (which I also covered by counting the number of people joining), so essentially if 2 people use the command, I want them to be sent into a dedicated voice channel, if other 2 users do the same, they also get sent into their own dedicated voice chat on the server. Thanks <3

Comment: This is what I was suggested trying 
discord.utils.get something to do with guild.voice_channels

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you write the title of the question as a short title instead of half of a long sentence? It will make it easier for people to find your question and guess if they will be able to answer it before they have opened it. Try to make it so someone can understand what your question is about in a single glance. Separating the content into multiple paragraphs can also help readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user isn't connected to a voice channel, you can't make him join one.
The only thing you can do is moving someone to another channel with the [`move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.move_to) function.

To track which user is connected to a channel, you could have a dict which takes a channel id as a key and the two users as a value:

```py
channels = {}

async def join(ctx, i=[0], c=[0]):
    author = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    if i[0] == 0:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"""Voice chat #  {c[0]}""")
        channels[channel.id] = [#Your two users]
        i[0] = 0
        c[0]+=1
    i[0] += 1
    if i[0] == 2:
        i[0] = 0
    print(i[0])
    return i[0]
```

A example of how to use `move_to`:

```py
@commands.command()
async def move(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID) #ID must be an INT
    await ctx.author.move_to(channel)
```

If you want to change the channel's [user limit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=limit#discord.VoiceChannel.user_limit):

```py
channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"""Voice chat #  {c[0]}""")
await channel.edit(user_limit=2)
```

If you want to check how many [members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.VoiceChannel.members) are connected:

```
async def check_channels(ctx):
    for channel_id in self.channels.keys():
        channel =  bot.get_channel(int(channel_id))
        if len(channel.members) == 0:
            await channel.delete()
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I've got 1 more question, I wan't to go through every voice channel and check if they have no people in them, and delete them. Also, how can I set the limit of users on 1 channel?

Comment: First of all, I want to tell you that you are a god, second of all, I'm having troubles with using self, how do I use it, because when I try to copy paste it, doesn't seem to be working as it requires self as an argument.
Sorry that I don't know how to do all of this, completely new to python, I love C#

Comment: When you create a class, every function must have `self` as their first argument. To call it inside the class, you just have to write `self.function_name`. If it has other arguments than self, `ctx` for instance, you just have to write `self.function_name(ctx)`. If you want to call it outside a class, you can create an instance of it and write `instance.function_name(ctx)`. Here is a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) on python classes.